# MathML support in Adobe Digital Editons for EPUB

Tags: epub, mathml

I am using MathPlayer to render MathML in an XML file. I am creating an EPUB. The ebook reader which I am using is Adobe Digital Editions. But it is not rendering the mathematical equations properly. Does ADE support MathML? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I don’t think ADE comes anywhere near supporting MathML. The practical way to write an e-book with lots of math in it is to create it in PDF format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADE doesn't support MathML. If you are dependent on using ADE, your best bet is to use PNG graphics in your EPUB. This will enable your EPUB + Math to work on many more readers, since MathML is not well supported either inside or outside the browsers.

Some EPUB readers have incorporated the MathJax javascript library into their implementations. You can see which readers have MathJax support here: http://www.mathjax.org/resources/epub-readers/

Hope this helps.

Best regards,
Jean K.

Comment: Always useful to confirm: http://www.bisg.org/what-we-do-12-152-epub-30-support-grid.php

Comment: FWIW, we're in the midst of updating the EPUB 3 support grid. We're working with the IDPF conformance test suite and testing is underway right now. The new conformance test suite will definitively answer questions of support that were previously left up to vendor specifications and crowdsourced information. That said, I think it is doubtful that the actual Adobe Digital Editions will natively support MathML any time soon. Maybe we should convince them to install MathJax! ;)